# How do I make my `OutputDebugString` messages be clickable links in Visual Studio output window?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I output log/warning/error messages by `OutputDebugString()` so they are readable in "output" window of Visual Studio.

I want to make those messages to be links. After clicking they will open predefined source file and put a cursor on predefined line, much like this happens with compiler errors.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Format your output string in a special way:

```
file_path(line): message
```

where `file_path` is a full absolute path of a file to open by click, `line` is a number of line cursor to be put on and 'message` is anything else.

Visual Studio parses such a string when you double-click it and opens the file.

Example with C++ and `boost::format`:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string errMsg = "Yay! Fancy link!";
    std::string formatted =(boost::format("%s(%i): in function \"%s\": %s\n\n")  
                          % __FILE__ % __LINE__ % __FUNCTION__ % errMsg ).str();
    OutputDebugStringA(formatted.c_str());
}
```

Comment: `file_path` can be a relative path, but I don't know for certain relative to _what_.  Full paths always work.  (Unrelated, Macros are great for adding paths and line numbers)

Comment: Hmm, no, this certainly doesn't work on my machine.  You probably ought to mention what add-in you've got installed that makes it clickable as well as the VS version.

Comment: @Hans I'm using for now latest VS2013 with tons of addons, so I've checked it also on a Windows 7 virtual machine where I have a snapshot with Visual Studio 2010 fresh install (no addons, no service pack). I've used sprintf instead of boost. It works fine. I think I've used it in VS2008 too, but not sure as it was long ago. Make sure that you don't have any spaces around braces (inside or outside) and before colon, but that you have a space after colon. Also, I have no idea how path with spaces handled.

Comment: @Hans Try to pass directly to `OutputDebugStringA` something like `c:\projects\foo\foo\main.cpp(9): in function "main": Yay! Fancy link!`. Does it work for you?

Comment: I found the answer in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12369186/17034).  You have to **double-click** the line.  That was not intuitive.

Comment: @Hans Wow! Didn't know that we have such question already for C#.

Comment: Double-click is consistent way to follow these types of links in the error list, build output, and everywhere else I've seen in VS.